# What does $"some-string" mean in bash?

Tags: bash

What does it mean in bash when a quoted string is preceded by dollar character?

Example:

```
echo $"foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes the string subject to translation. From the man page:

> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will cause the string to be  translated  according
>          to  the  current  locale.   If  the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored.  If the string is
>          translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.